# Why one data folder is almost 70 GB size?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have elasticsearch installed on k8s, where fluentd put data with logs everyday and average size of indice is about 1GB, I removed indices older than one week yesterday manually ( I don't have any delete policy) because storage is approaching to maximum ( I have 100 GB storage per node) however, from some reason, one folder is still almost 70GB, do you know why?

````
[elasticsearch@elasticsearch-master-1 indices]$ c^C
[elasticsearch@elasticsearch-master-1 indices]$ du -hs * | sort -hh
48K     7GFwGZHoQ4uM8KCpLc-Oxg
48K     W0A74hl-Qw-2dIpx65hXFA
60K     BNKGjyyZRheQOKpF4jPRmw
64K     2oGMlHa9TOC5IAtG4E8N2A
64K     5SidHjfxS-yvghDJL2y7Ug
64K     NpCZAg2_R0SItwTY4n7cKA
88K     leZHbZpEQW6A6xWCgVZTJQ
116K    lA7py6UYQpS6kMBAcD-ShQ
216K    pXqc9yQYSfCnSyi8Zf3qCA
432K    J0zWpVVoQr6AUZwzMDObtA
5.3M    gJ-_TDd9Q4KZAqjrSnz3RA
41M     sMjw45GHSgah5a0c7PH1oA
378M    nR-A9ZnxQdGhnNP0Snadhg
451M    bCEnvyh4RuKHMD2H0EbS_w
476M    4EhSvr21QROhgVjY8yExIg
502M    p7o2nSSjQiyFDQr4S5XECQ
504M    U98Y4gbqS5mBnQeu-uXZyg
530M    ciE5Uy6wQ1272mECz0VBgg
553M    qydbdCS4SpuI9ISA-LRisg
67G     hJZCqt9OQ8yRsRBlLCiPYg
[elasticsearch@elasticsearch-master-1 indices]$ pwd
/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/indices
[elasticsearch@elasticsearch-master-1 indices]$ ```
````

Comment: Could you post the result of GET */_stats/store?human=true (in kibana) ? It will help to understand which index is so heavy. Then we will be able to investigate why :)

Comment: @PierreMallet http://json-parser.com/0ea13543

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking the stats you posted it seems the cuplrit is the `fluentd-2021-11-17` index.

```
{
    "fluentd-2021-11-17": {
        "uuid": "hJZCqt9OQ8yRsRBlLCiPYg",
        "primaries": {
            "store": {
                "size": "66.5gb",
                "size_in_bytes": 71466871581,
                "total_data_set_size": "66.5gb",
                "total_data_set_size_in_bytes": 71466871581,
                "reserved": "0b",
                "reserved_in_bytes": 0
            }
        },
        "total": {
            "store": {
                "size": "133.2gb",
                "size_in_bytes": 143041475223,
                "total_data_set_size": "133.2gb",
                "total_data_set_size_in_bytes": 143041475223,
                "reserved": "0b",
                "reserved_in_bytes": 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You certainly had an incident this day that created much more logs than usual.

Comment: thank you Pierre for the reply, I don't know why but I missed this indice from some way... I removed it and it works like a charm!